# I Have a problems with qoutes in my bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, aliases

how to do so that in this script which searches for something from the database. he searched for it and changed its name in the terminal.
I have a problem with the quotes here.
Maybe anyone know how to fix it?

```
spr-ustawien()
{
echo -e "\e[31;43mSprawdzanie Ustawień\e[0m \e[101mIP $1\e[0m"
intertube=0
while [ $intertube -ne 1 ]; do
ping $1 -c 5
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
sshpass -p (pass) ssh -t (user)@$1 "
sudo sqlite3 config.sqlite "SELECT * FROM settings" |grep "SALE_POINT" | awk '{sub(/SALE_POINT/,"\033[1mPunkt Sprzedaży:\033[0m")}1' &&
exit "
echo -e "\e[1;5;32mSprawdzony\e[0m"
intertube=1;
else
echo -e "\e[1;5;31m!!! JEST OFFLINE !!!\e[0m"
break
fi
done
}
```

Comment: `"Punkt Sprzedaży"` should be `\"Punkt Sprzedaży\"`?

Comment: Still doesn't work.                                                                                                          awk: line 1: syntax error at or near [                                                                            Error: incomplete input

Comment: @Black4Killer update the question please with the current state of code `sub(/SALE_POINT/,"\033[1mPunkt` should be if i understand the case `sub(/SALE_POINT/,\"\033[1mPunkt`if you don't want to translate a special character then it must start with \CHAR where char is the special char, you can also debug it when starting the same command with `echo` so it will show you exactly what it's doing meaning `echo sudo sqlite3 config.sqlite "SELECT * FROM settings" |grep "SALE_POINT" | awk '{sub(/SALE_POINT/\,"\033[1mPunkt Sprzedaży:\033[0m\")}1' &&
exit "`

Comment: @djdomi they showed me: ```bash: /home/black/.bash_aliases: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `)' ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the basic problem is that quotes don't nest the way you're using them in the `ssh` command. That is, in this command:

```
sshpass -p (pass) ssh -t (user)@$1 "
sudo sqlite3 config.sqlite "SELECT * FROM settings" |grep "SALE_POINT" | awk '{sub(/SALE_POINT/,"\033[1mPunkt Sprzedaży:\033[0m")}1' &&
exit "
```

The `"` in `"SELECT * FROM...` is actually a close quote (matching the open quote on the previous line), so rather than `SELECT * FROM settings` being inside two layers of quotes it's actually completely unquoted (and as a result, the `*` will expand to a list of files in the local directory, causing who-knows-what chaos).

As djdomi said in a comment, you can see what the arguments to `ssh` look like after the shell has parsed them (and therefore what'll be sent to the remote system to be executed) by replacing the `ssh` command with `echo`. When I run this:

```
echo "
sudo sqlite3 config.sqlite "SELECT * FROM settings" |grep "SALE_POINT" | awk '{sub(/SALE_POINT/,"\033[1mPunkt Sprzedaży:\033[0m")}1' &&
exit "
```

it prints:

```
sudo sqlite3 config.sqlite SELECT file1.txt file2.jpg FROM settings |grep SALE_POINT | awk '{sub(/SALE_POINT/,033[1mPunkt Sprzedaży:033[0m)}1' &&
exit
```

The most direct solution is to escape the inner double-quotes, so the local shell will pass them through to the shell on the remote system:

```
sshpass -p (pass) ssh -t (user)@$1 "
sudo sqlite3 config.sqlite \"SELECT * FROM settings\" |grep \"SALE_POINT\" | awk '{sub(/SALE_POINT/,\"\033[1mPunkt Sprzedaży:\033[0m\")}1' &&
exit "
```

Note tht you must escape *all* of them, even the ones inside the single-quoted `awk` command, because those single-quotes don't mean anything to the local shell.

... but I'd recommend simplifying this a bit. I don't see any reason that `grep` and `awk` need to be run on the remote system rather than the local system (and the `exit` command isn't doing anything useful, since it's going to exit anyway). So you could move the `grep` and `awk` commands outside the `ssh` command:

```
sshpass -p (pass) ssh -t (user)@$1 "sudo sqlite3 config.sqlite \"SELECT * FROM settings\"" |
    grep "SALE_POINT" |
    awk '{sub(/SALE_POINT/,"\033[1mPunkt Sprzedaży:\033[0m")}1'
```

And I always hate to see `grep` used before `awk`, when `awk` is perfectly capable of doing everything itself:

```
sshpass -p (pass) ssh -t (user)@$1 "sudo sqlite3 config.sqlite \"SELECT * FROM settings\"" |
    awk '/SALE_POINT/ {sub(/SALE_POINT/,"\033[1mPunkt Sprzedaży:\033[0m"); print}'
```

I'd also recommend double-quoting all variable references (e.g. `ping "$1" -c 5` instead of just `ping $1 -c 5`), and replacing this:

```
ping $1 -c 5
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
```

with just:

```
if ping "$1" -c 5; then
```

And finally I'd recommend `printf` instead of `echo -e` -- it's way more predictable. `printf` is a bit more complex to use -- the first argument is a format string that tells it how to print any remaining arguments, and it doesn't automatically add a newline at the end (so add one explicitly with `\n`) -- but it's less likely to break because of some change in the shell's version of `echo` (as happened to me a while back...). So use e.g.

```
printf "\e[31;43m%s\e[0m \e[101m%s1\e[0m\n" "Sprawdzanie Ustawień" "IP $1"
```

Oh, and I always recommend running your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) -- it'll point out many common mistakes and bad practices.